# Retina display and screen capture on macbook pro

Tags: objective-c, macos, retina-display

In my  color picker application I use CGWindowListCreateImage to create an image that is a portion of the current user's screen and then I zoom the image up till showing pixels.

This is the code that i use to capture the image

```
img = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectMake(point.x,fd ,width ,height),
                                  kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow, 
                                  (CGWindowID)winNum, 
                                  kCGWindowImageDefault);
```

And this is the code that I use in drawRect to draw it scaled.

```
CGContextScaleCTM (ctx, ZOOM, ZOOM);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, image_position, img);   
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

I can't test this code on a macbook pro with retina display and I'm really curious to know if it works correctly!

I have some doubt about the scale part... because I can't understand how it looks with doubled pixels. What do you think about this code? someone with a retina display has just tried to use scale that way?

Comment: The captured image doubles the size (window size * scale)